# Extrude and automatically remove overlapping faces

Tags: extrude

My question is identical to [this one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102290/overlapping-faces-while-extruding-corners), which was asked almost 6 years ago. I'm wondering if there have been any feature changes since then that automate the process.

Consider this image:

[image]

On the right I've extruded the yellow section in the middle and manually tidied up by removing the overlap at the top of the extruded column and welding the verts. Is there a way these days to make the extrusion and get Blender to do the tidying up automatically? I'm using v3.6.2.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30874/push-faces-like-sketchup https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/162634/how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-extra-faces-created-when-extruding-inwards/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/228336/correct-way-to-extrude-inward-intrude/228340#228340

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos, I think he's looking for "dissolve orhogonal edges" option.

Comment: Extrude Manifold was the answer. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/228336/correct-way-to-extrude-inward-intrude/228340#228340